# Sort grouped dataframe based on the time variable colum

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with ID, Name, datetime and value. When I use dtypes of this DF, I get

```
ID - int64
time - object
value - int
```

I want to group the dataframe by ID and then sort the rows on the order of time. I tried the following,

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
p= df.groupby(['ID'])
```

Then I tried,

```
p.sort_values(['time'])
```

but getting an error,

```
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'sort_values' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

so then I tried,

```
p['time'].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values())
```

and this seems to work for that column alone. I am not able to sort all the columns. I want to sort the entire dataframe based on the time variable after grouping the ID. I know this might we very easy. But have been trying it for a long time without any result. Can anybody help me in doing this?

Comment: @jezrael this one is giving ID as single row and number of rows previously as number of columns and losing all the other columns. Which is not correct.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. Maybe help `print df.set_index('value').groupby(['ID']).apply(lambda x: x['time'].sort_values()).reset_index()
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular case, can't you just sort instead of groupby?  E.g.

```
>>> df
   ID       time  value
0   1 2016-03-05     10
1   1 2016-01-04     20
2   2 2015-05-05     30
3   3 2016-01-02     40
>>> df.dtypes
ID                int64
time     datetime64[ns]
value             int64
dtype: object
>>> df.sort_values(["ID", "time"])
   ID       time  value
1   1 2016-01-04     20
0   1 2016-03-05     10
2   2 2015-05-05     30
3   3 2016-01-02     40
```

This will sort them based on the 2-tuple key of (ID, time) for each row, and would work in the same way even if there were multiple `value`-like columns:

```
>>> df.sort_values(["ID", "time"]) # different df
   ID       time  value  value2
1   1 2016-01-04     20     200
0   1 2016-03-05     10     100
2   2 2015-05-05     30     300
3   3 2016-01-02     40     400
```

Comment: Thanks. It works well. Pretty simple way of doing this.!!